# how to set background of TextView to @android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame

Tags: android, textview, android-background

i want to set the below xml code programmatically. i know about textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable...) but i am not able to set textView background to @android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame. Please suggest me suitable method.

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

Comment: did this finally work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the pattern of the code below:

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.dialog_holo_light_frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use and of the standard android resources you have to use **android.R.** folder rather than just **R.** . **R.** is for your own project. So do it like below -

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.dialog_holo_light_frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
yourTextView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.dialog_holo_light_frame);
```

Comment: This answer is practically identical to at least **2** previous ones. What does it add to them?

Comment: It's due to latency in StackOverflow server as well as in internet connection of mine, in addition with how long before had I opened the question in explorer, so.

Comment: For your information, I didn't downwote. The one who appreciated my comment is *supposed* to have done that.